# Can I see who started a currently running job on my SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

We recently built a small application that allows our end-users to remotely start jobs on a SQL Server. To figure out whether or not a job is already running, we use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    sj.job_id
    , name
FROM 
    msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sja
    INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS sj 
        ON sja.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE 
    sja.start_execution_date IS NOT NULL
        AND sja.stop_execution_date IS NULL
```

This works like a charm, but ideally, in case a job already was started, we'd also like to show the id/name of the user who started the job in question.

I checked the different sysjobs* tables, but was unable to locate any columns that could allow us to obtain that information.

I'm hoping I'm simply overlooking something, and that someone would be able to help me figure out a shortcut to get this done. My alternative would be adding an extra table of my own containing a job-id and username whenever the job is started, and pulling in the name that way.

Comment: Interesting question.  I am not sure if you can get this information.  I know you can get what credentials the job was run under from `msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory` but that will often be different to who actually started the job.

Comment: Thanks, Fred. In our case, all jobs are executed under the same credentials (the server from which the job is fired off is on a different network). Apart from that, the message column only will list the user on the completion of the job: 

`The job succeeded.  The Job was invoked by User <user>.  The last step to run was step 1 (Do something for 30 secs).`

Thanks, though :)

Comment: Actually, the last comment kind of answered my question in itself. Because all jobs start under the same credentials, I'll *have* to build my own custom table, using the username from the other network to record the username. Still, if there's a way to figure out the user-id natively in SQL Server, I'd still be interested in hearing it, as we want to move the server into our network at some point.

Comment: Just wondered if this might help you.. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49006/check-if-sql-agent-job-is-being-executed-manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up building our own table to store details of jobs being started:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[dwh_jobs](
    [job_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [started_by_user_name] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [start_time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [end_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [run_time] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [rows_affected] [bigint] NULL DEFAULT ((0))
)
```

We then created a couple of stored procedures to log the start and end time of the jobs being started:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_job_start]
    @job_id uniqueidentifier
    , @started_by_user_name nvarchar(255) 
    , @start_time datetime
AS 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO msdb.dbo.dwh_jobs 
        (job_id, started_by_user_name, start_time, end_time, run_time, rows_affected)
    VALUES
        (@job_id, @started_by_user_name, @start_time, NULL, NULL, 0)
END
```

This is the end proc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_job_end]
    @job_id uniqueidentifier
    , @started_by_user_name nvarchar(255) 
    , @start_time datetime
    , @end_time datetime
    , @run_time nvarchar(255)
    , @rows_affected bigint
AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE msdb.dbo.dwh_jobs 
    SET 
        end_time = @end_time
        , run_time = @run_time
        , rows_affected = @rows_affected
    WHERE
        job_id = @job_id
        AND started_by_user_name = @started_by_user_name
        AND start_time = @start_time
        AND end_time IS NULL
        AND run_time IS NULL
        AND rows_affected = 0
END;
```

Lastly, we added a proc to look up which user started a particular job:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_job_lookup_user]
    @job_id uniqueidentifier
    , @started_by_user_name nvarchar(255) OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @started_by_user_name = started_by_user_name
    FROM
        msdb.dbo.dwh_jobs
    WHERE
        start_time = (SELECT MAX(start_time) FROM msdb.dbo.dwh_jobs 
            WHERE job_id = @job_id AND end_time IS NULL)

END;
```

It's not perfect yet, as there's no maintenance to clean out non-closed jobs yet, but it'll allow us to at least figure out which user started a particular job.

Answer (score 0):

Check

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
```

> Executed as user: xxx\yyyy. The step succeeded.

Comment: Hi. This would indicate who started a job but only after it finished. We're hoping to figure out who started a job that currently is executing.

Comment: I am not sure, but it might show the succesfull step. If that is true, then make the first step as dummy one that would execute in a moment and in that case you can see. But it is only if the record appear there after each step, not after execution of full job.

Comment: This shows what account the job ran as.  In most cases, it will be the SQL Server agent job, or a proxy that has been created.  This does not show who actually started the job.